# Python Flask Hosting on Windows 10 IIS server

Tags: python, flask, iis

I Want to Host my Python Rest API on Windows 10 IIS server.

First I tried to host a sample application but can not able to that.

**my_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello IIS from Flask framework.'

@app.route('/Hello')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**web.config**

```
<configuration>  
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Python FastCGI"
            path="*"
            verb="*"
            modules="FastCgiModule"
            scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe|C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
            resourceType="Unspecified"
            requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="my_app.app" /> <!-- {name_of_file}.{name_of_flask_app}-->
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test" />
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\app.log" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have tried the below tutorials but it is not working for me.

1. https://medium.com/@rajesh.r6r/deploying-a-python-flask-rest-api-on-iis-d8d9ebf886e9
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ma1UvzqF82Q&ab_channel=ShobhitWalia

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error : [see the Error scrennshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocPac.png)

I need help....  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want IIS host python application, you need to install python, and then you need to add module mapping in IIS. Here are the steps:

1. First install python on your computer.
2. Enable CGI:

[image]

After successful installation, you will see "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" and Handler Mappings:

[image]

3. Enter "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions", add a new ISAPI or CGI Restrictions:

[image]

4. Enter "Handler Mappings", then add Module Mapping(%S %S needs to be added or an error will be reported):

[image]

Finally we can successfully access the python Application:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Can you see python in your Handler Mappings?

[image]

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

There is nothing in web.config. All my settings are for the entire IIS:

[image]

Click "Directory Browsing":

[image]

Enable it:

[image]

Comment: HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration

Comment: Are your steps the same as mine?

Comment: Is it because of the project? Try to deploy a site, there is only one test.py file in the site.

Comment: this is a sample project for the IIS host test

Comment: Wait. I will check that

Comment: I post my web.config.

Comment: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: You need to enable Directory Browsing.

Comment: https://developpaper.com/using-iis-to-deploy-flask-website-on-windows-platform/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925688/windows-10-iis-url-error-python-flask-rest-api