# IIS Web Application run python script

Tags: python, iis

I have ASP.NET Web Application (IIS). From web form page, I am running dos bat file that include some python script file. Dos bat file is running fine but python script file is not executed. What security do I need to configure?

ASP Web Form -> [Run Batch File]->inside batch file-> python helloworld.py

Thanks you

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 IIS runs everything in system session, so it can simply fail to locate Python executable that way.

Comment: If you want to run python in IIS, you need to install python, and then you need to add module mapping in IIS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906568/python-flask-hosting-on-windows-10-iis-server/64907715#64907715

Comment: Thank I have found that solution. But what I need is to execute python script calling in window dos batch file.